# Are there are any pdf viewers that currently support video?

Tags: video, pdf, latex

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and it seems like video support is broken (or not available) in any pdf viewer in the repositories.

I would love to be proven wrong!

The test file is here:
http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf

There is a video on page 23 that should play.

(I'm aware of pdfpc, which in principle has it's own way of including and playing videos in pdf files, but I could not even get that to open its own example file either, in Ubuntu 16.04).

And yes, I did try installing the phonom vlc backend for okular.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

It seems the example you're trying to play is not just a video, but also Flash. It has an embedded Flash video player, which is then used to play the videos in the example document you listed.

I am not aware of any PDF viewers on Linux that support embedding Flash (or any other browser plug-ins). Even Chromium doesn't seem to support Flash in PDFs.

Comment: Just to clarify, looking around on the web suggests that this file used to play with older versions of okular, evince, etc.  EDIT: this was my impression, but maybe this is wrong?  In any case, I would be happy with any way to reliably add video to a pdf in a latex presentation and then view it on linux.

Comment: The example from http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/PDFmovie.html seems to work basically fine for me in evince.

Comment: You're right, that examples does play for me.  It is not quite usable in a presentation, however, as the fullscreen behavior is not reliable in either evince or okular.

Comment: My current best solution is: downgrade acroread to 9.4.1, and then include use the "flashmovie" latex package to include videos.